# Antlr4: Another "No Viable Alternative Error"

Tags: parsing, expression, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I have checked similar questions surrounding this issue but none seems to provide a solution to my version of the problem.
I just started Antlr4 recently and all has been going nicely until I hit this particular roadblock.

My grammar is a basic math expression grammar but for some reason I noticed the generated parser(?) is unable to walk from paser-rule "equal" to paser-rule "expr", in order to reach lexer-rule "NAME".

```
grammar MathCraze;

NUM : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
WS  : [ \t]+ -> skip;
NL  : '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
NAME: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
ADD: '+';
SUB : '-';
MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
POW : '^';

equal
    : add # add1
    | NAME '=' equal # assign
    ;
add
    : mul # mul1
    | add op=('+'|'-') mul # addSub
    ;
mul
    : exponent # power1
    | mul op=('*'|'/') exponent # mulDiv
    ;
exponent
    : expr # expr1
    | expr '^' exponent # power
    ;
expr
    : NUM # num
    | NAME # name
    | '(' add ')' # parens
    ;
```

If I pass a word as input, sth like "variable", the parser throws the error above, but if I pass a number as input (say "78"), the parser walks the tree successfully (i.e, from rule "equal" to "expr").

```
equal                 equal
 |                     |
add                   add
 |                     |
mul                   mul
 |                     |
exponent              exponent
 |                     |
expr                  expr
 |                     |
NUM                   NAME
 |                     | 
"78" # No Error      "variable" # Error! Tree walk doesn't reach here.
```

I've checked for every type of ambiguity I know of, so I'm probably missing something here.

I'm using Antlr5.6 by the way and I will appreciate if this problem gets solved. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added a paragraph concerning `no viable alternative at input 'variable78'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your style of expression hierarchy is the one we use in parsers written by hand or in ANTLR v3, from low to high precedence.

As Raven said, ANTLR 4 is much more powerful. Note the `<assoc = right>` specification in the power rule, which is usually right-associative.

```
grammar Question;

question
    :   line+ EOF
    ;

line
    :   expr   NL
    |   assign NL
    ;

assign
    :   NAME '=' expr                 # assignSingle
    |   NAME '=' assign               # assignMulti
    ;

expr // from high to low precedence
    :   <assoc = right> expr '^' expr # power
    |   expr op=( '*' | '/' ) expr    # mulDiv
    |   expr op=( '+' | '-' ) expr    # addSub
    |   '(' expr ')'                  # parens
    |   atom_r                        # atom
    ;

atom_r
    : NUM
    | NAME
    ;

NAME: [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
NUM : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
WS  : [ \t]+  -> skip;
NL  : [\r\n]+ ;
```

Run with the -gui option to see the parse tree :

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar
$ alias grun
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ grun Question question -gui data.txt
```

and this `data.txt` file :

```
variable
78
a + b * c
a * b + c
a = 8 + (6 * 9)
a ^ b
a ^ b ^ c
7 * 2 ^ 5
a = b = c = 88
```

.

**Added**

Using your original grammar and starting with the `equal` rule, I have the following error :

```
$ grun Q2 equal -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:7='variable',<NAME>,1:0]
[@1,9:10='78',<NUM>,2:0]
...
[@41,89:88='<EOF>',<EOF>,10:0]
line 2:0 no viable alternative at input 'variable78'
```

If I start with rule `expr`, there is no error :

```
$ grun Q2 expr -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:7='variable',<NAME>,1:0]
...
[@41,89:88='<EOF>',<EOF>,10:0]
$
```

Run `grun` with the `-gui` option and you'll see the difference :
running with `expr`, the input token `variable` is catched in NAME, rule `expr` is satisfied and terminates;
running with `equal` it's all in error. The parser tries the first alternative equal -> add -> mul -> exponent -> expr -> NAME => OK. It consumes the token `variable` and tries to do something with the next token `78`. It rolls back in each rule, see if it can do something with the alt of rule, but each alt requires an operator. Thus it arrives in `equal` and starts again with the token `variable`, this time using the alt `| NAME '='`. `NAME` consumes the token, then the rule requires `'='`,  but the input is `78` and does not satisfies it. As there is no other choice, it says there is no viable alternative.

```
$ grun Q2 equal -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:7='variable',<NAME>,1:0]
[@1,8:7='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:8]
line 1:8 no viable alternative at input 'variable'
```

If `variable` is the only token, same reasoning : first alternative equal -> add -> mul -> exponent -> expr -> NAME => OK, consumes `variable`, back to `equal`, tries the alt which requires `'='`, but the input is at EOF. That's why it says there is no viable alternative.

```
$ grun Q2 equal -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:1='78',<NUM>,1:0]
[@1,2:1='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:2]
```

If `78` is the only token, do the same reasoning : first alternative equal -> add -> mul -> exponent -> expr -> NUM => OK, consumes `78`, back to `equal`. The alternative is not an option. Satisfied ? oops, what about  EOF.

Now let's add a NUM alt to `equal` :

```
equal
    : add # add1
    | NAME '=' equal # assign
    | NUM  '=' equal # assignNum
    ;

$ grun Q2 equal -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:1='78',<NUM>,1:0]
[@1,2:1='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:2]
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input '78'
```

First alternative equal -> add -> mul -> exponent -> expr -> NUM => OK, consumes `78`, back to `equal`. Now there is also an alt for NUM, starts again, this time using the alt `| NUM '='`. `NUM` consumes the token `78`,
then the parser requires `'='`, but the input is at EOF, hence the message.

Now let's add a new rule with EOF and let's run the grammar from all :

```
all : equal EOF ;

$ grun Q2 all -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:1='78',<NUM>,1:0]
[@1,2:1='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:2]
$ grun Q2 all -tokens data.txt
[@0,0:7='variable',<NAME>,1:0]
[@1,8:7='<EOF>',<EOF>,1:8]
```

The input corresponds to the grammar, and there is no more message.

Comment: It's incredible how powerful Antlr4 is. It's obvious I still have more to learn to command it properly. But my problem still remains. I still can't figure out why the original grammar can't parse '"variable" successfully.

Comment: Your updated answer is insightful and clears up a lot. I didn't know grun consumes EOF as well, I thought it was just there to mark the end of input and it's weird considering I've written other grammars that don't even acknowledge EOF as a token.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't answer your question about why the parser can't reach `NAME` in `expr` I'd like to point out that with Antlr4 you can use direct left recursion in your rule specification which makes your grammar more compact and omproves readability.
With that in mind your grammar could be rewritten as

```
math:
    assignment
    | expression
;

    assignment:
        ID '=' (assignment | expression)
    ;

    expression:
        expression '^' expression
        | expression ('*' | '/') expression
        | expression ('+' | '-') expression
        | NAME
        | NUM
    ;
```

That grammar hapily takes a `NAME` as part of an `expression` so I guess it would solve your problem.

If you're really interested in why it didn't work with your grammar then I'd first check if the lexer has matched the input into the expected tokens. Afterwards I would have a look at the parse tree to see what the parser is making of the given token sequence and then trying to do the parsing manually accoding to your grammar and during that you should be able to find the point at which the parser does something different from what you'd expect it to do.

Comment: Your grammar does not take into account precedence rules between the operators.

Comment: Yes it does. Antlr recognizes the precedence according to the first specified left-recursive alternative. Just try it. One thing you might consider though is that you probably want the alternative matching an exponent to right-associative...